# Error trying to run mstest on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, mstest

I´m trying to configure MSTest build plugin on jenkins, but I´m getting the following error:

```
Path To MSTest.exe: mstest.exe
Result file was not found so no action has been taken. file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/jobs/SoftwrenchvNext/workspace/TestResult.trx
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.MsTestBuilder.perform(MsTestBuilder.java:144)
```

The configuration simply specifies TestResult.trx as ResultFileName. This file is not versioned, and I expect it to be created on each build.

What needs to be done for that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I too had this exact same error message!

My recommendation is to replace the "Run unit tests with MSTest" step. with an "Execute Windows batch command" step.  This worked for me.

**Command**

```
del TestResults.trx
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:Example.Tests\bin\Debug\Example.Tests.dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx
```

Using this technique you may still use the "Publish MSTest test result report" step specifying...

**Test report TRX file**

```
TestResults.trx
```

Good luck!

Also, you can "simulate" the "Continue on failed tests" functionality with an "EXIT" call, seen below.

```
del TestResults.trx
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:Example.Tests\bin\Debug\Example.Tests.dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx /nologo
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: The MSTest plugin for Jenkins does not support spaces in the path to the workspace.

Comment: If true, that's about stupid, because the default install path has spaces.

Comment: The *first* thing you do when developing a plugin is create directories with spaces in it to test that scenario. (Well, maybe the second or third, but you do test it with some spaces here and there).  Geeze Louise.  Back to the command line.  :(

Comment: I took the liberty to enhance the answer a tad.  I hope that was ok.

Answer (score 29):

After some investigation I was able to get MSTest to work in Jenkins by doing the following:

Select Manage Jenkins

[image]

From within the Manage Jenkins choose Configure System

[image]

In Configure System you will need to find MSTest and Add your MSTest configuration

[image]

Enter your configuration as you see fit. Mine appears as follows:

[image]

Save the configuration and then go to your build project and configure the appropriate items like shown below:

[image]

One thing to note is that I did not follow any of the steps listed on the author's site because they didn't seem to make any sense to me. I did however read the code and spent some time digging and realized that the missing piece was in the  Configure System page of Jenkins.

Cheers!

Comment: Worked for me too. Now I need to figure out why Jenkins is ignoring my Test Categories.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up on configuring the MSTest through the easy panels - it would not find the test dll, so like the guy above I used the batch command. I have added my batch command below because it addresses some issues with previous answers that they do not take into account that you have to delete the .trx file before each run, or give it a unique name or tests will fail.

Here is my solution running in Jenkins as a batch command:

```
"C:Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/MSTest.exe" /resultsfile:"%WORKSPACE%/MyAppTest_%BUILD_NUMBER%.trx" /testcontainer:"%WORKSPACE%/Components/ebox2/Central/MyApp/MyAppWeb/trunk/MyAppTest/bin/Release/MyAppTest.dll" /nologo /category:Build
```

Note the inclusion of %BUILD_NUMBER% in the .trx file name, which gets round the problem of jobs failing because of duplicate .trx file.

Note also that /category:Build allows you to choose the tests you want. You set up the category in the tests themselves:

```
[TestCategory("Build"), TestMethod()]
```

I use this because I have some Selenium tests which I have not figured out how to run in Jenkins yet, or if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to notice: This does not work with .NetCore, just with the regular .Net Framework: (See https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1213#issuecomment-338561792 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/238572/mstest-command-line-reports-no-tests-to-run.html)

I used a batch job in Jenkins with something like the following code:

`dotnet test src\Folder\Project.csproj --logger:trx`

Please find the full reference for `dotnet test` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21