# How to exclude tests using "/Category" from mstest on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, mstest, gitlab-ci

Before you point me out the other questions please read on...

I am running a mstest argument from Jenkins (not sure if this at all relevant) and want to exclude tests that do not belong in a particular category.
Including tests in a category works a treat using the `/category:CI` but when i use it to exclude test using `/category:!CI` it doesnot work. It just says `no tests to execute`. I am %110 sure that there are tests in my container that are not in this category.
I am using mstest test for VS2010.

```
mstest.exe /testcontainer:%%i /runconfig:%TestSettingFile% /category:"!CI" /resultsfile:Results.trx
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong

**EDIT**
I have found that this command doesn't work when running it from Jenkins but it works fine through cmd on the local box - any current bugs with Jenkins in regards to this?

Comment: Apparently there is a known issue with MSTest+Jenkins when there are spaces in the path to mstest.exe.

Try changing the path to it (in Jenkins config) to DOS style `...\PROGRA~1\mstest\etc` or use Windows Batch Command instead.

Comment: There definitely looks to be a problem there - Do you know the item number or a link to this issue on Jenkins?

Comment: Looks like using "Execute Windows batch command" could be a way forward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112717/error-trying-to-run-mstest-on-jenkins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly enough putting the category as the last argument seemed to have worked. Try moving the arguments if you are seeing the same issue.

**EDIT**

I only leave the answer above as a reference even though it is totally incorrect.

As it turns out Jenkins batch command ignores " ! " mark so to escape it i had to use a " ^ " character.

so my category is now listed as `/category:"^!CI"`

Comment: I see the same issue on GitLab CI. Using the escape character worked there as well.