# No tests to execute msTest

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, command-line, mstest

I'm trying to run .NET unit tests on the command line using MSTest

My command is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:"full path of dll" /resultsfile:TestResults.trx
```

When run it returns

> Starting execution...
>   No tests to execute.

The unit test runs perfectly fine in VS 2012 IDE.

What do I need to do to get it running on the cmd line please?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:full path of dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx
```

Ie without the " " around your path to the dll

Comment: It solves my problem in the sense that it throws a different error now. It seems to been complaining about spaces in the directory name. Thanks

Comment: So I tried it with out the speech marks and moved my project to a directory with no spaces but it still says "No tests to execute."

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:full\\path\\to\\dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx

Comment: using \\ in file path

Comment: Note that this does only work with the .Net Framework, not with .NetCore or .NetStandard! Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52964726/5536006

Comment: FranzHuber23 is correct.  For .Net Core, you just instead run `dotnet test MY_UNIT_TEST_PROJECT.csproj`.

Answer (score 36):

In my case I started getting "No tests to execute" on command line when I switched to .NET Framework 4.6.1. I had to switch from MSTest.exe to VSTest.Console.exe for it to work.

Some instructions on how to use vstest.console.exe are here -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx

Also check this out -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this was actually what helped me go through this. I'm using .NET Framework 4.6+

Comment: In case you use .NET Core, the command is: dotnet test my.tests.assembly.dll

Answer (score 6):

It turns out I needed to use the nunit-console as my tests are written in the nunit framework.

Live and learn I guess

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a .Net Framework unit test project.
2. Manage nuget packages -> Remove "MSTest.TestFramework" and "MSTest.TestAdapter" nuget packages.
3. Add an assembly reference to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework", 10.0.0.0.
4. Rebuild the project and verify that the output path(bin\debug) does not have any _MSTest_TestAdapter*.dll assemblies
   This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same message "No tests to execute".

What I found out was a silly mistake on my part - in command line, I was using MVCProj09292016.dll(my project DLL) for *testcontainer:/* instead of using MVCProj09292016.**Tests**.dll(my test project assembly).

Bottom line is that check whether you are using correct dl name in command line:it should be your **MStest** project assembly, in my case it is MVCProj09292016.Tests.dll

Answer (score 1):

## Try using vstest.console.exe

### Example:

**vstest.console.exe [assembly.dll] /logger:trx;LogFileName=[filename].trx**

1.Open Cross tools command prompt (use windows search)

Choose: Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2009


[[image: 1]]

[image]
2. Open the Cross Tools Command line.
3. Navigate to your project's Bin folder
4. Copy/Paste your Bin folder's patch inside Cross Tools Command Line
 Example:
[image]
Than run the following command:
**vstest.console.exe [assembly.dll] /logger:trx;LogFileName=[filename].trx**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using XUnit. **The problem was that I didn't had included xunit.runner for the project**. It's not very obvious, since it only adds a reference to packages.config and csproj-file. It's not visible in Visual Studio references list. It is still obvious in a way that without a runner, how does the mstest know how to run xunit tests.

Comment: How can you know whether or not you have included `xunit` in your project? In my case I have a solution, containing all test projects, and while entering `xunit` in the Solution Explorer, I see nothing.