# No tests to execute from MSTest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have read [No tests to execute msTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770501/no-tests-to-execute-mstest)

I'm trying to run a unit test (MS unit tests) from the command line. It's my first time attempting this.

My command works fine (no syntax errors), which is

> mstest /testcontainer:C:\Users\me\source\repos\Test03\UnitTestProject1\bin\debug\UnitTestProject1.dll

The problem is I always get the following response in the console

> Loading C:\Users\me\source\repos\Test03\UnitTestProject1\bin\debug\UnitTestProject1.dll...
>   Starting execution...
>   No tests to execute.

My unit test is simply

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void AddPositive()
        {
            var bll = new ConsoleApp1.Bll();
            var result = bll.Add(2, 5);
            Assert.IsTrue(result == 7);
        }
     }
```

Why does it not find the test as I've followed the instructions from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#testcontainer?

The solution as a whole targets 4.6.1 , I'm using VS 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Did you do a debug build?

Comment: @JoePhillips: the DLL is in a debug folder, at least

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes but it could have been built before any tests existed. There's really not much else that could go wrong here

Comment: Yes, I did a debug build. Also I tried a release build and updated the path. I am aware of the difference between the 2 build solutions :)

Comment: What versions (mstest, visual studio, target framework of the unittest project) are you using? On 'newer versions' you might want to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx

Comment: Updating to use vstest.console actually works and runs all the tests. This can be moved to an answer for me @Caramiriel

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `mstest.exe`, you need following reference in your project file:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

If you have instead (which seems to be the default for newly created test projects):

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.3.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.3.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

you need to use `vstest.console.exe`

Please note that [VSTest.Console.exe is optimized for performance and is used in place of MSTest.exe in Visual Studio 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! It really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and it took me some time to figure out. The actual solution is in the comments.

My Tests are getting discorvered using `vstest.console.exe`:

`Visual Studio Enterprise 2017`:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options for further info.