# MSTest Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, .net-5

I have a .NET 5.0 unit test project that I'm trying to execute via the command line using MSTest.

I'm using a command like the following to run the unit tests:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:tests\bin\Debug\net5.0\UnitTestProject.dll
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
Unable to load the test container 'tests\bin\Debug\net5.0\UnitTestProject.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've seen similar questions on here such as [Visual Studio 2017 - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4) but the answers make reference to editing an app.config file, which I do not have in my project.

Is this just a limitation of using .NET 5.0 and MSTest in the way I'm trying to? Or is there something I can do to allow MSTest to run the tests?

Comment: Do you **have** to use `MSTest.exe` or could you give `dotnet test` a try?

Comment: @mu88 so full story ... I need to use a COM library in the project so can't use dotnet test and the docs say to use MSTest instead. I was successfully using dotnet test before the inclusion of said COM library and all was working fine, but ever since it's inclusion I've had a whole heap of problems, this being the last one

Comment: Before .NET Core / .NET 5.0, I'd have recommended to use Fusion Log Viewer to detect assembly binding errors. I don't know whether it still works, but with the old .NET Framework it did a lot good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've done more playing around with this and because I need to use a COM library as part of the project it seems that it's not possible to use .NET 5.0/.NET core stuff in anyway.

I did a test using .NET Framework 4.7.2 - I made a unit test solution using this version of the framework, added a COM library and ran the unit tests at the command line and all worked. The only gotcha with this was I had to use `vstest.console.exe` and not `MSTest` to run the tests.

Using `MSTest` gave me the `No tests to execute` issue. But it seems like using `vstest.console.exe` is the answer to this - [No tests to execute msTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770501/no-tests-to-execute-mstest)